# JsonApiDotNetCore.BaseJsonApiController<TResource, TIdentifier> not able to limit routes

Tags: c#, .net-core, json-api

I have created a custom controller Which inherits from BaseJsonApiController<> and i have overridden methods like GetAsync, GetById, PatchResource, PostResource. So while running the application getting error from swagger that says :

> An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGeneratorException: Ambiguous HTTP method for action - Controllers.RaceController.GetSecondaryAsync. Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger/OpenAPI 3.0

Also, even if I use specific service then also it generates all the controller endpoints
Example :

```
public class RaceController<TResource, TIdentifier> : BaseJsonApiController<TResource, TIdentifier>
        where TResource : class, IIdentifiable<TIdentifier>
        where TIdentifier : struct
{
  public RaceController(IJsonApiOptions options, IResourceGraph resourceGraph, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IGetAllService<TResource, TIdentifier> getAllService) : base(options, resourceGraph, loggerFactory, getAllService)
  {
    
  }

[HttpGet]
public override async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = base.GetAsync(cancellationToken);
    return Ok(response);
}


[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetById")]
public override async Task<IActionResult> GetAsync(long id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var response = await base.GetAsync(id, cancellationToken);
    return Ok(response);
}
}
```

Now in the above example it will create endpoints for PostAsync as well which it should not as per the documentation.

I wanted to get only the routes endpoint generated for those the methods has been overridden from the BaseJsonApiController but currently it is generating all the endpoints. I am using version 5.3.0 of JsonApiDotNetCore

Comment: The error specifically mentions ` Controllers.RaceController.GetSecondaryAsync` - have you checked it?

Comment: Also please read [ask] and provide a [mre]. Currently there is not enough info to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, I have overriden only the GetAsync method from BaseJsonApiController<> and not the GetSecondaryAsync so when the swagger is loading up getting this issue